# Why does SOQL return related records when run directly but not when run with Apex?

Tags: apex, soql

I have a SOQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT Id, OwnerId, IsDeleted, AboutThirtyFieldsTotal__c, ...
(SELECT Id, IsDeleted, OverFiftyFields__c, ...
 FROM Borrowers__r )
FROM Loan__c WHERE LSC__c = '0051F00000ocJMdQAM'
ORDER BY CreatedDate LIMIT 200
```

The entire query is about 1,500 characters long.

When I run this query directly (by selecting it in VS Code and executing it with the command pallet) I get the correct result, with columns for `Borrowers__r.FirstName__c` with multiple rows for each of the related records.

If I run the exact same query from within `Database.query`, I *don't* get the related data, only the data from `Loan__c` with no data after the last field in the outer `SELECT`?

Why do I get related data when I directly execute the SOQL but not when it's executed by Apex?

Comment: Typically this is as a result of the context user's permissions. How are you confirming that you don't have any related child records when it is run in apex?

Comment: I have a temporary Apex file that I'm using which I have this line: `System.debug(LoanController.getLoans('0051F00000ocJMdQAM', 'lsc'));` I execute this by highlighting it and using "Execute Anonymous Apex" in the command palette. It is this line that _doesn't_ have the related records. However, within `getLoans` I `System.debug(query);`, and when I highlight that query and use the command palette to "Execute SOQL," I _do_ get the related records.

Comment: I don't know exactly which user I'm acting as when I execute anonymous Apex, but I did check that the user I _think_ I'm running as has "Read, Create, Edit, Delete, View All, Modify All" for both objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you debug an `SObject` record, the output is not necessarily going to show you everything in memory, as it coerces the complex data type into a `String` to render.

What you observe when you `system.debug(someRecord)` in this case is incomplete. If you were to `system.debug(someRecord.Parent__r.Field__c`, you would see these fields are in fact populated.

Alternatively, you can `system.debug(JSON.serialize(someRecord))` and see a more complete representation.

Comment: ty, that did the trick. I actually confirmed I'm getting the related data by printing out `LoanController.getLoans('0051F00000ocJMdQAM', 'lsc')[0]`.

Comment: Thank you for the system.debug(JSON.serialize()) trick.  That'll come in handy.